# Treasure tables in 3.5: roll per monster or per encounter?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, treasure

It recently occurred to me that each monster in the MM has a treasure value, I've been rolling on the treasure table per encounter, am I supposed to roll per monster that has a treasure value over "none"?

Example: There are 2 orcs in a room making a CR1 encounter for a lvl 1 party do I roll on the treasure table for each Orc or for both orcs together?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/treasure.htm#monstersWithTreasure) are pretty explicit on that particular point, at least for *standard* loot:

> Refer to the treasure tables and roll d% once for each type of treasure (Coins, Goods, Items) on the Level section of the table that corresponds to the creature’s Challenge Rating (**for groups of creatures, use the Encounter Level for the encounter instead**).

So for groups, you roll once, using the total CR/encounter level.

There's no discussion of groups with mixed treasure type.  But since rolling for treasure is completely optional in the first place (as the DM you can assign whatever treasure you like!) this isn't exactly a huge problem.