# How do the treasure tables work for mixed groups of creatures?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, treasure

In reference to the question [Treasure tables in 3.5: roll per monster or per encounter?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22950/treasure-tables-in-3-5), how does the system expect a GM to handle groups of creatures with mixed treasure types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It...doesn't**

The random treasure rules aren't really one of 3.X's prize pieces of writing. There's no table that I'm aware of that provides advice on how to hand out loot for mixed-creature encounters, and modules (*Expedition to Undermountain* etc) are almost wholly useless as examples since all of their loot comes pre-done with little explanation or justification from which a process could be extracted. If you're determined to do loot randomly, the best advice I could give you would be to roll on everyone's table(s) until the total wealth is appropriate for the encounter.